# Quadratic polynomial in ${\Bbb C}$ that vanishes on three different points of a complex line

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Here is my **question**:

> Let $f(x,y)\in {\Bbb C}[x,y]$ be a [quadratic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function#Two_variables_case). If $f$ vanishes on three different points (say, $p,q,r$) of a complex line
>   $$
> L:=\{(x,y)\in{\Bbb C}^2\mid ax+by-c=0\},\quad a,b,c\in{\Bbb C},
> $$
>   then do we have $f(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)\in L$?

---

The only idea I have come up so far is that on the real plane ${\Bbb R}^2$, three different points define a quadratic polynomial $f(x)\in {\Bbb R}[x]$. This might be a useful to be generalized to the complex case. But I really don't see how to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The restriction $f\left|_L\right.$ is a one-dimensional quadratic polynomial, which vanishes on three different points, i.e. has three distinct zeros. Therefore, $f\left|_L\right.=0$.